# Wix - uninstall remove files but not folders

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I created a wix installer using heat cmd.
On uninstall all files are removed but not all folders are removed.
this the relevant part of my code:

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="$(var.PlatformProgramFilesFolder)">
    <Directory Id="companyDir" Name="companyName">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="AppName">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" >
          <Directory Id="bin" Name="bin">
          <!-- Auto-start via Registry -->
          <Component Id="AppNameAutoStartUp" Guid="MYGUID">
            <Condition>AUTOMATIC_START_UP=1 OR Installed</Condition>
              <RegistryValue Id="App.rst" Root="HKCU" Action="write" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" Name="AppName" Value="[#AppName.exe] -sc" Type="string" />
          </Component>

          </Directory>
        <Directory Id="docs" Name="Docs">
        </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="ConfCompanyDir" Name="Company">
      <Directory Id="CONFINSTALLFOLDER" Name="AppName">
        <Directory Id="CONFINSTALLDIR" >
          <Directory Id="conf" Name="conf">
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <!-- Shortcuts and Directories for Shortcuts -->
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="AppName">
      <Component Id="ProgramFilesShortcut" Guid="MYGUID">
        <Condition>DESKTOP_SHORTCUT = 1</Condition>
        <Shortcut Id="desktopAppName" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="AppName" Target="[#AppName.exe]" WorkingDirectory="bin" Icon="AppIcon.ico">
        </Shortcut>
        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramFilesShortcut" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="MYGUID">
          <Shortcut Id="startmenuAppName" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="AppName" Target="[#AppName.exe]" Icon="AppIcon.ico" WorkingDirectory="bin" Arguments="-s">
          <!-- Set the AppID in order to get toasts to work -->
          <ShortcutProperty Key="System.AppUserModel.ID" Value="Company.AppName" />
        </Shortcut>
        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
</Directory>
```

The Docs folder is removed on uninstall but the bin folder is not removed (although it is empty, all the files are removed).
Does anyone have any idea why it is not removed?

Answer (score 0):

I added code like this to your *Feature* element:

```
<Component Directory='INSTALLDIR'>
  <RemoveFolder Id='CleanupApplicationFolder' On='uninstall' />
</Component>
```

So you should **change** *INSTALLDIR* to *main folder* (and it should uninstall all).

Comment: I am not sure I understood you answer. I tried to add your line between my lines like this: (but it did not work)          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="AppName">
            <Component Id="CleanupFolders" Guid="MYGUID">
              <RemoveFolder Id='CleanupApplicationFolder' On='uninstall' />
            </Component>
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" >

Comment: Set `Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"` to that _Component_ and then try

Comment: I cannot set a `Directory` attribute because it is nested under a Directory element. I get compilation error if trying to do so.

Comment: oh my, sorry i forgot to mention, add it to Feature element ^^ `<Feature Id='TestProductFeature' Title='Wix File Product Feature' Level='1'><RemoveFolder Id='CleanupApplicationFolder' On='uninstall' /></Component></Feature>` like that. I edited answer~